# Can the Diablo 3 download be scheduled?

Tags: diablo-iii

My peak internet download quota is a bit small at the moment, but I have a decent amount of offpeak quota. Unfortunately the offpeak period is from 2am-8am, and I don't really want to stay up that late just to kick off a download. Is is possible to schedule the Diablo 3 download to occur at a certain time?

Comment: Why can't you just leave it running when you go to bed and let it run all night?

Comment: @Wikwocket because that would use up my "peak" quota for the time spent downloading before 2am. In Australia most internet plans only have a certain amount that you can download each month, you pay more each month for higher quotas. My particular plan has separate quotas for 2-8am (offpeak) and 8am-2am (peak).

Comment: Is there a way you can have your Internet "turn on" at a set time? You should be able to set it up via the modem...

Answer (score 7):

This is a fairly crude method, but may work.

1. Create two batch files

   - `connect.bat`:

     > netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=ENABLED
   - and `disconnect.bat`

     > netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=DISABLED
   - **n.b.**, change "Local Area Connection" to whatever connection your internet is going through
2. Set up a pair of Windows tasks in the "Task Scheduler" (search for it in the start menu)

   - Have one task run `connect.bat` at 2 AM, and `disconnect.bat` at 8 AM.
   - **You must check "Run with Highest Privileges"** otherwise the scripts will do nothing.
3. Open up the downloader/installer and begin downloading.
4. Rght click on `disconnect.bat` and "Run as administrator".  This should disable your network adapter, and with it your internet connection.  (Verify that the download stops)  When Windows automatically runs it's counterpart `connect.bat`, it will essentially plug you back in.

   - If you need to manually override and connect back, just run the `connect.bat` file as an admin.  You might want to test run this before blindly letting it run overnight.

Comment: You can type `ncpa.cpl` in the Run prompt (Windows Key + R) to find it out the name of your connection on your computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a macro like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to wait a certain time then click the "download" button.

`Sleep, 120000

Click`

Answer (score 1):

You can't schedule the D3 downloader from within the utility itself.  However you can use third party software like [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) and similar programs to apply a per-program bandwidth scheduler that can cut off or throttle D3's downloads between given times.